# Prevent Multiple Logins with WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a WebApi project with Token authentication and works fine, but for my Business logic, I can't allow the user to be connected in two different clients which is Android. I was thinking of some logic with the database, put a flag to determinate weather is online or not but it does't feel right. There's any lib along with WebApi that I could do this? Thanks!

Comment: How would you determine when a user has "logged out" so they can be authorized from a different device?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't. The token is not recycled, when the user log out i just erase the token and the next time it would be generated another one!

Comment: It sounds like first you'd need to define some business logic and/or user experience by which either the user explicitly logs out (sends an API request to invalidate the token) or by which a token is automatically considered invalid after a certain amount of time.  Once that logic is defined, you'd be able to start researching to implement it.

Comment: So basically, the user could just be logged out if it have a internet connection so I could validate? Only that way I could guarantee if he's out or not.